# How do you count days for brit milah (circumcision)?

Tags: halacha, brit-milah

My understanding is circumcision should be performed on the eighth day. Does this include the day the child was born? So if born on Monday, would circumcision be on the following Monday, or should it be 1 week + 1 day (Tuesday)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The day of the birth is included in counting towards the eighth day of life:

> A Brit [Milah](http://www.dailyhalacha.com/displayRead.asp?readID=1228) should be performed on the infant's eighth day ([including](http://www.mazelmoments.com/blog/2810/rules-for-scheduling-a-bris-brit-milah/) the day of birth), after sunrise. If the circumcision was performed before sunrise on the eighth day, it is nevertheless valid, so long as it took place after daybreak.

(from http://www.dailyhalacha.com/displayRead.asp?readID=1228 Rabbi Eli Mansour)

Comment: ...and the day beings at nightfall.

Answer (score 0):

[Breishit 17:12](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9597&st=&pgnum=210) uses the phrase בן שמונת ימים which (loosely) means "an 8-day old".

When the Torah uses the phrase בן followed by a number to refer to someone's age, it is counted from the date of birth, or the first day of a person's life.

What, perhaps, may confuse the count is if a child is born during twilight. In such situations, you may need to check with a rav to verify exactly what the Hebrew date of birth is to know when the 8th day is.

Comment: "It's obvious from this verse that the counting begins from the day of birth": apparently your intuition into Biblical Hebrew is better than mine.

Comment: @msh210 explain how you would translate בן שמונת ימים

Comment: (re your comment) "someone who has eight days" or, more idiomatically, "an eight-day-old"

Comment: @msh210 Huh?? You translated it the same way as I did. So, I'm not following your 1st comment.

Comment: If it means an eight-day-old, how is it obvious then that the day of birth is included in the eight?

Comment: @msh210 Do you turn an additional year old on the day of your birthday or the day afterwards?

Comment: @ezra: The day of your birthday, which means that the first day was *not* counted. If the first day was counted, you would gain a new year the day before. The modern way to celebrate birthdays is contrary to the answer's interpretation (not to say it isn't true; only that it's not obvious to modern readers). If you were born on Sunday, then on next Sunday you would be, in modern terms, 1 week (or 7 days) old, not 8 days old. Just like a full year from Sunday you would be 1 year old, not 1 year + 1 day.

Comment: @msh210 I don't know how much more I can argue this point. There are  numerous cases where the Torah uses the phrase "ben <number>". Are you positing that when later it says that Avraham was *ben tishim vatesha shana" when he was circumcised that they didn't count that from the day he was born. The Torah is off by 1 year? Isn't the day you were born the 1st day of your life?

Comment: @MeniRosenfeld See ^^. Isn't the day you're born the 1st day of your life? How is this system different from other days that you count? Do you count from zero or from one? Regardless of how this translates to "modern birthdays", the point is that when the Torah uses the term *ben <x>" the counting starts from the day of birth. If you know of another explanation, by all means, provide an example.

Comment: All I'm saying is that your entire answer (the part that answers the question) is "well, the Torah says 'בן שמנת ימים' so obviously it includes the birth day" and it isn't obvious at all. As @Meni points out, English doesn't work that way; and even if it did, who's to say Biblical Hebrew does?

Comment: @DanF: Well, there's a reason that in computer science, and sometimes in mathematics, counting starts at 0. It's more consistent this way. That said, I would say that the day you are born is the 1st day of your life, and you are 0 days old. Just like when I'm starting a journey, I'm on the first mile of the journey, and I have traveled 0 miles. Only when I complete the first mile I can say I've traveled 1 mile; and only when I complete the first day of my life, I can say I'm 1 day old. Also, when I am born I am in the 1st year of my life, but I am not 1 year old.

Comment: @MeniRosenfeld OK - I got the idea. (I also understand why arrays in some computer programming languages start from 0.) Fine, my translation of "days old" may not be a great English translation. But, it doesn't change the halachic aspect that one counts 8 days which includes the day of birth to determine circumcision. At this point, Let's leave things at our disagreement of interpretation or "preciseness".

Comment: @msh210 See ^^ as well as my edits. If it's still incorrect, please suggest what may make it better or clearer.

Comment: It's not that your answer is incorrect, it's that it states as obvious something that is actually counterintuitive. I wouldn't normally say that a baby is 1 day old 15 minutes after he's born. That's just the quirky way the Torah counts time.

Comment: @Daniel I've edited the question, anyway to eliminate the "unobvious".